# Unable to retrieve users from Quickblox

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I've just started to play around with Quickblox. I created 3 users and could not get any from database. Any ideas would be appreciated.
(frameworkVersion 2.6.4)

```
 [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin: self.loginTextField.text password:self.passwordTextField.text successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser* _Nullable user) {

        NSLog(@"+++LOGGED IN:%@", response);


        //Getting all users
        QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:100];
        [QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {
         NSLog(@"+++GOT %lu Users",(unsigned long)users.count);
       } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                 NSLog(@"---NO Users:%@",response.error);
        }];




    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
        NSLog(@"NOT --- LOGGED IN:%@", response.error);
      }];
```

Console output:

```
  +++LOGGED IN:[QBResponse], status: 202 
  ---NO Users:
   Error reasons:{
     errors =     {
       base =         (
          Forbidden
        );
     };
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can only be 2 reasons.

1. It is not allowed in settings of your application to download users
   http://admin.quickblox.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/settings

Check "Allow to retrieve a list of users

2.You have created a session without user. ( You have completed this step already )

```
 [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:@"login" password:@"password"
                     successBlock:[self successBlock] errorBlock:[self errorBlock]];
```

Comment: Wow, first reason solved my problem. I'm sure they should mention this in docs. I don't have much reputation here to give a plus. Thank you anyway @SevenDays

Comment: Thank you too! I will raise this question to QB team. Please mark question as answered

Comment: @SevenDays I am facing similar issue. I have already check marked and user has been created from backend side we are searching for user with user ID in quick blox from app side. But not getting result. Please help me out. Thanks